# Form sending all HTML from nav bar

Tags: php, html, html-table

i'm having a bit of an issue in that when Im working with a script that allows the conversion of HTML into CSV files.

The actual table data is sent and parsed absolutely fine, however one of the issues im finding is that the html that the form sits inside to trigger this, ends up sending the entire document as HTML, and thus in the excel file I get given all the HTML markup in the navigation bar.

```
    <form class = "element brand place-right" action="client-summary.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value = "
     <?php echo htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($table, '<table><th><tr><td>')); ?>"> 
    <!--<input value="Download XLS" type="submit" class="bg-dark xls-download">-->

        <button type ="submit" class="button fg-white xls-download">
            <i class="icon-download-2 on-left bg-dark"></i>Download Report
        </button>
    </form>
```

This sits inside my navigation bar at the top of my page, however when I

```
$table = $_POST['data'];

echo $table;
```

on the client-summary.php page I get all of the HTML in the navigation, AS WELL AS the table data.

All of the HTML comes before the table data, and I assume this is because HTML AND JAVASCRIPT gets displayed first over php. But i'm not sure why the html before is posted in data, as data is only the table itself.

If anyone can shed some light on this i'd be really grateful, I'm not really very experienced with php to troubleshoot this myself.

Comment: Look at the actual HTML code your script generates, and [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) that HTML code.

Comment: why are people voting this down without giving feedback or comments?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem, It turns out that its a mistake of me trying to bundle too much stuff into one include(), In one of my includes I made a call to the navigation, in turn it displayed the HTML on the next page, meaning that the script which turned that data into an excel file would include all the other 'gunk'.